# Quantum-Break: Why did Paul ask something he should already know?

Tags: video-games, quantum-break

Paul asked Jack a Question in the first half of Act 3, to which he should already know the answer:

> Paul used the second time machine built by Will to travel back from the end of time in 2016 back to 1999.
>  17 years later, he asks Jack for the location this time machine, although he should exactly know the location of it, as he used it to get to the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Towards the end of the game Will had the time machine from the swimming pool moved from the Ground Zero location. It was from the previous location that Paul had returned to the past, and exited at Ground Zero rather than at the pool

Comment: But if the time machine was still located at the swimming pool at the end of time, then Paul would know it would be moved there at some point, because that's where he entered it.